# Differences when overloading operator+

Tags: c++, overloading

Something peculiar happened when I was overloading operator+

I have a singly-linked list, and I overloaded the operator+ and operator=

Here's my implementation for both (edit: with insertFront and copy constructor):

```
 AnyList::AnyList(const AnyList& list)
{
count = list.getCount();
first = list.getFirst();
AnyList a;
a.setFirst(first);
a.setCount(count);

Node *current = first;
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    a.insertFront(current->getData());
    current = current ->getLink();
}
}
```

-

```
      void AnyList::insertFront(int value)
{
Node *newNode = new Node;
newNode -> setData(value);
newNode -> setLink(first);
first = newNode;
++count;
}

AnyList AnyList::operator+ (const AnyList& list) const
{

Node *current = first;
Node *listCurrent = list.getFirst();

int sumHolder = 0;
AnyList temp;
while(current != NULL)
{
    sumHolder = current ->getData() + listCurrent ->getData();
    temp.insertFront(sumHolder);
    current = current ->getLink();
    listCurrent = listCurrent ->getLink();
}

return temp;
}


AnyList& AnyList::operator=(const AnyList& rightSide)
{

if(&rightSide != this)
{
    Node *travel = rightSide.getFirst();

    first = rightSide.getFirst();

    Node *original = first;

    while (travel != NULL)
    {
        original ->setData(travel ->getData());
        original ->setLink(travel ->getLink());
        travel = travel->getLink();
        original = original ->getLink();
    }
}

return *this;
}
```

Here is what is in main:

```
AnyList mylist;
AnyList mylist2;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    mylist.insertFront(i);
}
for (int i = 10; i < 20; ++i)
{
    mylist2.insertFront(i);
}

mylist.print();
cout << endl << endl;
mylist2.print();
cout << endl;
AnyList sumList = mylist + mylist2;
sumList.print();
cout << endl;
```

My output is as follows (which is the output I desired):

```
    9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 

19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10

10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28
```

So, my question is, when I instead write:

```
    AnyList sumList;
sumList = mylist + mylist2;
sumList.print();
```

I get a bad-access error when it goes into the print function and attempts to return the data from the function getData()

I'm super unaware of why this is the case, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: show at least `insertFront()`. Do you have a copy constructor???

Comment: Not that the first case doesn't even use `operator=` - it uses the copy constructor.

Comment: Or move constructor, I should say.

Answer (score 3):

`mylist + mylist2` creates a temporary, whose destructor is called at the end of the full expression. Your assignment operator does a shallow copy, so if the memory is freed by the temporary's destructor being called, `sumList` will now have dangling pointers.

Read up on how to do deep copies.

To test this, you can temporarily remove the destructor. Just to test though - you'll need it if you're managing resources.

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
AnyList sumList = mylist + mylist2;
```

calls a copy constructor rather than `operator=` (see copy initialization)

And this

```
sumList = mylist + mylist2;
```

Indeed calls `operator=`

Most probably your copy constructor performs a deep copy, which is correct and doesn't lead to a crash. Your `operator=` does shallow copy and you get a crash as a result

Answer (score 0):

Why do you get an error in one case and not the other? Because `AnyList sumList = mylist + mylist2;` *does not* call the = operator but instead invokes the copy constructor. Whereas

```
AnyList sumList;
sumList = mylist + mylist2;
```

calls the default constructor and then invokes the = operator.

You haven't shown us enough of your code to be sure why it is crashing when you use the operator= but I'd suggest that Luchian Grigore's answer probably has the right of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment operator copies the "first" pointer from the other list, so that both lists end up sharing the same nodes. (The loop in the operator is just a long-winded way of doing nothing, since you're assigning each node's data an pointer to themselves). Presumably, the list has a destructor which deletes its nodes, so you will end up with both lists trying to delete the same nodes; hence the error (or some other undefined behaviour).

If you want the list to be copyable and assignable at all, which is perhaps not a good idea, then you will have to do a "deep" copy, creating new nodes for the assigned-to list. Also, remember to delete the old nodes before reassigning your pointers to them.

Better still, unless you're learning how to implement a linked list, use the containers provided by the standard library.